# Cynthia Wessell's Dictionary of Affect

Tags: data-request, dictionary

Is [Cynthia Wessell's dictionary of affect](http://www.amsciepub.com/doi/abs/10.2466/pr0.105.2.509-521) available as an open dataset? Looks like a it's closed-source executable (and $175) on the [official website](http://perceptmx.com/index.asp?WCU=psychometrics).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Well**, you picked a very commercial word list so even 'finding' a copy of the dataset could lead to legal problems or results you can't publish.

**But**, to get a taste, there is a web-app that I found after chasing down some broken links. It's apparently endorsed by Cynthia herself. Check it out <s>[here](http://sail.usc.edu/~kazemzad/emotion_in_text_cgi/DAL_app/index.php)</s>.

**Now**, interestingly, the creator of that site posts a link to <s>[more info](http://sail.usc.edu/~kazemzad/emotion_in_text_cgi/DAL_app/info.html)</s>.

**And**, in that *more info* section is a URL that may help you greatly:

*dead link* <s>http://compling.org/cgi-bin/DAL_sentence_xml.cgi?sentence=This+is+a+great+web+app</s>

*replacement?* https://sail.usc.edu/dal_app.php

**So**, there you have it, a web interface to the DAL without having the DAL itself. For a sentence in the URL with words separated by a '+' sign, you get in return XML:

```
<sentence>
 <word>
  <token>This</token>
   <emotion>
    <measure type="DAL" valence="1.7500" activation="1.3333" imagery="1.0"/>
   </emotion>
 </word>
 <word>
  <token>is</token>
   <emotion>
    <measure type="DAL" valence="1.8889" activation="1.1818" imagery="1.0"/>   
   </emotion>
 </word>
 <word>
  <token>a</token>
   <emotion>
    <measure type="DAL" valence="2.0000" activation="1.3846" imagery="1.0"/>
   </emotion>
 </word>
 <word>
  <token>great</token>
   <emotion><measure type="DAL" valence="2.6250" activation="2.1250" imagery="1.0"/>
   </emotion>
 </word>
 <word>
  <token>web</token>
   <emotion>
    <measure type="DAL" valence="1.7778" activation="1.8750" imagery="2.8"/>
   </emotion>
  </word>
  <word>
   <token>app</token>
    <emotion>
     <measure type="DAL" valence="" activation="" imagery=""/>
    </emotion>
   </word>
  </sentence>
```

Comment: unfortunately this web based service doesn't work anymore..

Answer (score 1):

A new source of the DAL seems to be online

PDF Readme:

http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~julia/papers/dict_of_affect/DictofAffectinLang.README.pdf

and the dictionary (txt format)

http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~julia/papers/dict_of_affect/DictionaryofAffect